# PHP Image - Get parent pages source?

Tags: php

I'm planning on creating a responsive PHP image, that retrieves just the username of the current logged in user on a small forum. It's just going to help people on the forums see who last viewed the topic.

Using a PHP image, you can gather lots of information, but I need to find out what user is logged in and viewing the page.

I can't access any of the sites cookies, so would like to grab the html source from the page that loaded the image - from a specific part, that would hold the logged in users username.

Is there any way to grab any of the source code from the page that loads the image? I can use file_get_open() on the HTTP_REFERER session variable, but that wouldn't have any of the cookies or session variables.

Comment: Please start with some PHP tutorials first and come back when you face real problems with your code.

Comment: No you cant access cookies from another domain. You could get the refering pages source code by making a get request using the HTTP_REFERER

Comment: I'm asking a specific question - whilst the php image is downloading on a page, is there any way to gather information from the page it's hosted on - even if cross-domain?

Comment: Rule #1 of server-side scripting: *Tell, don't ask.*
Make the page tell the image who's logged in: `<img src="image.php?username=JoeUser">`

Comment: ^ but that's no good? I need to know who's logged in?

Answer (score 0):

If the original page is PHP, in the same server and using the same session, then those are of the original page too. But it's not always the case.

Say you got redirected from another website (could check referrer) or from another engine, say the page you came from is within the same server, same domain, but a different engine like .NET then your session wouldn't be the same but the cookies might.

But then again, if like Cake, the Cookies are protected (or mangled) then you will be able to access them, but you won't be able to decipher its content.

Depending on the how the previous page setup the cookies you could even read them if they came from the same domain (i.e. a.domain.org/ble.html -> b.domain.org/image.php). But is not safe to Assume.

See:
http://php.net/manual/en/session.security.php
http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/how-to-create-totally-secure-cookies

Note: Sometimes, you can't even trust `HTTP_REFERER` and `REMOTE_ADDR`. They can be spoofed easily.

Comment: Thank you, I just edited the original post, to describe more clearly what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Actually, the answer still holds its ground. You can't grab the Session from another Engine, in this case if you `file_get_contents` you are getting just HTML, so it won't be in your PHP session. You can still see the cookies if it comes from your same domain. You can't trust `HTTP_REFERER` nor `REMOTE_ADDR` (which would give you the client's address).

If You are building the Forum yourself, you can SPIT the image from a PHP file, then you would have the session available.

Comment: The HTML would suffice - but if I created a blank PHP document, and used file_get_open() on any website that I knew I was logged in to, it wouldn't show me as being logged in (which I assume is because the request comes from the server) - is there any way to get the pages html as if the user was logged in, possibly with the pages session id?

Comment: No, there is no way to do that. Your file_get_contents is originating from your server, whereas the client's request is generated from their own box. You can't share their state.

Answer (score 0):

If you check [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php), you will see that

> $_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']. It contains the raw value of the 'Cookie' header sent by the user agent

and for [$_COOKIE](https://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.cookies.php)

> The value of $_COOKIE is determined by the content of cookies received in the user agent's request.

You can see [$_SESSION](https://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) for the session variable